# Is there a way to validate @Column annotation constraints in Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Given an Entity with the following definition:

```
@Entity
class myObject (
    @Column(name = colName, nullable = false, length = 20)
    var myCol: String
) : AbstractJpaPersistableWithId<Int> {
    companion object {
        const val colName = "myCol"
    }
}
```

Then I want to create a dummy object like so:

```
val myObj = myObject()
myObj.name = "This is a string which is longer than 20 characters"
```

Is it then possible to validate the object in some way and get constraint violation results? In this case it would say the name is too long.

Something like:
`val violations = myObj.validate()`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use `@Size` from JSR 303 (Bean Validation) instead? I suggest that you go this way - JSR 303 integrates nicely with both Spring and Hibernate. You can check that `@Column` lenght is consistent with `@Size` in a unit test.

Comment: @Lesiak would I have to make that as a separate annotation in congruence with `@Column` length? And is that the recommended practice?

Comment: Yes, you would need 2 annotations. See https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-size-length-column-differences

Comment: @Lesiak could you perhaps show an example of how to get constraint violations with that?